# How to process the required file using exclude from the directory using Apache Camel File Component

Tags: file, apache-camel

I am using Apache Camel File component to process the JSON files in the directory.

Lets say i have a directory: C:/logs/myFiles/ which has 2 json files. I want to process only one of them.

C:logs/myFiles

```
- log1.json
- log2.json(this file will be created and updating during running the application)
```

So i want to process only log1.json and exclude the log2.json but the file name(log2.json) is dynamic which i am using from application.properties. This file will generate when i start the application with the name as dynamic value i have passed from application.properties.

How to use this dynamic filename in the exclude parameter of file component?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter` option and implement the `GenericFileFilter` where you can control in Java code which files to accept or not in a dynamic way.